# Reading the elements of Dropped Div inside the Dropper Container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have drop-able containers and some drag-able containers in my web page. The revert option is also applied so that if the drag-able object is not placed in the drop-able container it returns to it's initial position. Now when the it is correctly dropped, i want to read the value inside the paragraph tag of the dropped div..
how to do.....

```
<div id="forward" class="droppable">
```

```
<div class="mov text-center">
 <p class="player">Lionel Messi</p>
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".mov").draggable({
            revert: "invalid"
        });

        $(".droppable").droppable({
            classes: {
                "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-active",
                "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, in less words? Get the value of which div on drop? What do you mean by value? All of the html inside a certain div? Please make your question way more clearer than it is.

Comment: When you say dropped div value you mean want to know which player is being dropped in there - for example  ?